# How do you use a printer connected to mac from an xp machine?

Tags: mac, printer

I want to be able to use a printer that is connected to a mac osx 10.5 from my xp laptop.  I have shared the printer on the mac and I want to have the printer setup on my xp laptop so that it just works and I don't have to login into the mac computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Turn on printer sharing (Mac)

   [image]
2. Detect shared printers with Bonjour 2. Detect shared printers with Bonjour (Windows)

   [image]
3. Install the printer's driver 3. Install the printer's driver (Windows)

   [image]
4. Send documents to your new printer 4. Send documents to your new printer (Windows)

   [image]

If you do want to go the Samba way, here's Apple's official help document on printer [sharing with Samba or Bonjour](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh1770.html).